# Omitting "http://www." from my URL doesn't load the mobile site

Tags: url, mobile, http, browsers

I designed and uploaded a site on a mobile format. It shows up fine but ONLY if I type out the `http://`.

The client wants it to be as simple as possible.  How can I have it automatically insert the `http://www.`?

Comment: What shows up if you leave out the `http://www`?   Is it different for other sites on the device you are testing with?

Comment: I removed "DNS" from your question because it shouldn't have anything to do with DNS.   If `http://example.com/` and `http:/www.example.com/` both work when fully typed out, you have DNS set up properly.  It is browsers that add the `http://` in automatically.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are not managing URL redirects properly.

Firstly you will have to decide your preferred URL. And then you will also need to make sure other versions of URL should automatically redirect to preferred URL.

Example: Preferred URL: `https://www.example.com`

Then you need to make sure your other versions of URL automatically redirects to preferred URL like:

- `http:example.com`
- `http://www.example.com`
- `https://example.com`

In Apache hosting, you can easily manage by adding few lines of code in the .htaccess file.

Edited:
Following code can be used on Apache server to achieve above.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^example.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Perhaps you could include the "few lines of code" to help the OP otherwise your answer is incomplete.

Comment: Although having to manually type `http://` doesn't sound like a "managing URL redirects" issue. This sounds more like a browser usage problem?!